# Fluid amount in simulation

Tags: baking

I am trying to work through some Blender Tutorials and then try my own scene using that feature. I have a problem with a scene containing camera, lamp, cube set as fluid domain and a uv sphere set as fluid inflow.

My problem is that it just drips.

I am simply trying water from a tap, or a soda machine.

I have not allocated a inflow velocity in any direction assuming gravity would do that. When I tried a force in Z axis I just got a drip hitting the domain box harder.

I did try scaling the inflow sphere but that did not help. 
I also tried subdivision 2 in fluid boundary and Generate 1 in Fluid Particles.
I have set inflow velocity 1 in the sphere settings.

nothing seems to change.

What setting do I look at for more fluid. ?

(edit for spelling and some attempted changes)

Answer (score 4):

You need to set the *Inflow Velocity*. On its own (with no velocity) the Inflow only adds fluid to the domain within the Inflow volume if there is actually space to place it - ie, if the fluid has moved away to make space for some more fluid. Gravity does not act on the fluid in the Inflow and since you have no Inflow Velocity the liquid stays where it is and only those drops that break away from the surface tension will fall. Simply give it a velocity (eg, Z = -1) to allow it to flow away from the Inflow.

Comment: thanks for that. It is now working fairly well.  I obviously confused the tutorial which had a velocity x = value , and I had tried a z= 1 , it never occured to me to try a negative number. Now I can try adding a sink and keep building teh scene.  Thanks again for the help.

Comment: No problem - glad to help. Don't forget to mark the answer as 'Accepted' so others can more easily find it.